# How to actually use the NotImplementedError in python?

Tags: python, error-handling, abstract

I currently have a base class like so:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class BaseClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self._param1 = param1
        self._param2 = param2

    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("This needs to be implemented")
```

Now I have the abstract method foo that I want a user to override. So if they define a class like this:

```
from BaseClassFile import BaseClass

class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        super().__init__(param1, param2)
```

So here the method foo is not over-ridden / defined in the DerivedClass and when I create an object of this type it throws me a TypeError but I want to throw a NotImplementedError. How do I go about this.

The current error:

> TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class FF_Node with abstract methods forward

Comment: "when I create an object of this type it throws me a TypeError but I want to throw a NotImplementedError" - why do you want a NotImplementedError? TypeError is the standard, expected result here. NotImplementedError is what you'd get if you tried to actually *call* `BaseClass.foo` (which can happen through means like `super`).

Comment: I want it to be more informative to the user instead of just a TypeError. As in I want to give a custom error message.

Comment: The standard error is already pretty informative, no‽ And you’d need to rewrite `ABC`/`abstractmethod`; the `NotImplementedError` doesn’t really do anything here.

Comment: Ok! What you people say makes sense. But I was hoping I could get a NotImplementedError instead of the TypeError even if with the same desription. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that your error

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class FF_Node with abstract methods forward
```

is thrown the moment, your instace is created. When a method is declared as `@abstractmethod` it there must be a overwrite-method in classes inheriting this parent-class. Otherwise python will throw an error as soon as a instance of the child-class is created.

If you want your code to throw a `NotImplementedError` you need to remove the `@abstactmethod` decorator.

Abstract methods can not be called. There is no way the line `raise NotImplementedError()` is ever reached as log as it is a `@abstactmethod`.

Comment: You have explained it very clearly. Thanks!